# How to parse nested JSON objects in spark sql?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a schema as shown below. How can i parse the nested objects

```
root
 |-- apps: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- appName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- appPackage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Ratings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rating: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to treat each json object as a String and parse it using JSONDecoder parser.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you read in a json file and print the schema you are showing us like this:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("/path/to/file").toDF();
    df.registerTempTable("df");
    df.printSchema();
```

Then you can select nested objects inside a struct type like so...

```
DataFrame app = df.select("app");
        app.registerTempTable("app");
        app.printSchema();
        app.show();
DataFrame appName = app.select("element.appName");
        appName.registerTempTable("appName");
        appName.printSchema();
        appName.show();
```

Comment: just to add, above code does not need `registerTempTable` to work. You need to `registerTempTable` only when you need to execute spark sql query. Also `registerTempTable` had been deprecated since Spark 2.0 and had been replaced by `createOrReplaceTempView`

Comment: This is assuming that you know the schema. What if you are not sure about the schema of the nested object? How do you even create the schema of the nested object at all? I kinda asked this question in here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438774/query-json-data-column-using-spark-dataframes-but-not-sure-about-its-schema

Comment: I am having the same problem, and this code does not work for me. When I try to `select("app.element.appName")` (or the analagous fields for my case, I get the error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field element in...`. The element field is not present in the original json but is created to represent a jsonarray. but for some reason it isn't finding it

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
val nameAndAddress = sqlContext.sql("""
    SELECT name, address.city, address.state
    FROM people
""")
nameAndAddress.collect.foreach(println)
```

Source: 
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/02/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-spark-sql.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried doing it straight from the SQL query like

```
Select apps.element.Ratings from yourTableName
```

This will probably return an array and you can more easily access the elements inside. 
Also, I use this online Json viewer when I have to deal with large JSON structures and the schema is too complex:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 3):

I am using pyspark, but the logic should be similar. 
I found this way of parsing my nested json useful:

```
df.select(df.apps.appName.alias("apps_Name"), \
          df.apps.appPackage.alias("apps_Package"), \
          df.apps.Ratings.date.alias("apps_Ratings_date")) \
   .show()
```

The code could be obviously shorten with a f-string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var df = spark.read.format("json").load("/path/to/file")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df");
spark.sql("select apps.element.Ratings from df where apps.element.appName like '%app_name%' ").show()
```